# Tailwind background on hover not changing

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, vite

I have a array of objects that with information and a HEX color a property, I do a map of this array and pass the object to a react component, I do de-estructuring of the object, and I want that when I make hover on the object its background changes to the color of the object. In tailwin it fill be something like this
`hover:{color}` but it doesn't change. What could be the problem?

I have checked that the hover does work with a normal color, I have custom colors in the tailwind config file, and neither the background changed.

Comment: If you're setting the background color to, say, black, it should look like: `className: 'hover:bg-[#000000]'`. Could you provide snippets of your code and your tailwind config file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For specifying a background color on hover, the syntax must be: `className="hover:bg-[#HEXCODE]".

But this can only be done if you know the color beforehand. For dynamic colors, for eg.

```
const whiteColor = "#FFFFFF"; and className={`bg-[${whiteColor}]`}
```

This will not work. Tailwind needs the whole class to be together, so you can do something like:

```
const whiteColor = "bg-[#FFFFFF]"; and className={whiteColor}
```

This will work, as while compilation tailwind knows precisely what all classes are to be added.

So, for your use case, if you want dynamic colors, you can use `styles={{}}` if you do not know all the possible dynamic colors, else you can define them in the tailwind config file or use the above approach.

Comment: Thank you so much, your solution solve my problem, now its more easier to implement my idea.